# AODV HELLO packet

Tags: adhoc

I am currently working on an implementation of AODV protocol, One thing am not clear about is the use of HELLO packets. 

Are HELLO packets exchanged even before a route is established or HELLO packets are used to keep an existing route alive ?


**Note:** Also according to my understanding of AODV RFC 3561, HELLO packets are optional. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello packets used to construct neighbor table for all the nodes.  IN AODV you can use **Hello packets or Link layer detection** to create a neighbor list. in default AODV works with link layer detection. If you want to use hello packets you have to command the below lines in aodv.cc

//#ifndef AODV_LINK_LAYER_DETECTION

//#endif // LINK LAYER DETECTION

now you can verify hello packets operation using your trace files.